# Javascript Append objects from this array and create new array with object key value pairs appended

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I've got an array like

```json
 [{"Color Family":"BEIGE","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"BLACK","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"BLUE","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"CAMEL","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"GREEN","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"GREY","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"IVORY","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"KHAKI","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"PINK","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"WHITE","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Color Family":"YELLOW","Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Dark/Light Main Color":"DARK","Color Family":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Dark/Light Main Color":"LIGHT","Color Family":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Drop":"DEL 1","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Drop":"DEL 2","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Embroidery Family":"SATIN STITCH","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"COTTON","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"COTTON SILK","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"LEATHER","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"LEATHER/DENIM","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"LEATHER/TULLE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"SILK","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"TECHNICAL","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"TULLE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"VISCOSE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"VISCOSE/TULLE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"WOOL","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"WOOL/CASHMERE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"WOOL/COTTON","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric Family":"WOOL SILK","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric weight":"LIGHT","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Fabric weight":"MEDIUM","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"All-In-One","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Coats","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Corset","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Cut & Sew","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Denim","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Dresses","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Evening Dresses","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Furs","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Jackets","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Jersey Dresses","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Knitwear","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Knitwear Dresses","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Leather","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Outerwear","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Pants","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Shirts","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Skirts","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Line":"Tops","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Logo":"NO","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Logo":"YES","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Print/Jacquard Family":"ABSTRACT","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Print/Jacquard Family":"FLORA","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Print/Jacquard Family":"SEAL LOGO","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Print/Jacquard Family":"SKULL","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"3 BUTTONS","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"A-LINE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"BERMUDA","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"BOYFRIEND","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"BRA","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"BUSTIER","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"CAMISOLE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"COCOON","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"CROPPED","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"CULOTTE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"DROP MENS SHOULDER","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"FITTED","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"HARNESS","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"HIGH WAISTED CIGARETTE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"KNEE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"LONG","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"LONG CIGARETTE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"MENS","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"MENS SHOULDER","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"MIDI","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"MINI","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"OVER","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"PEAK SHOULDER","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"PEG","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"PENCIL","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"PEPLUM","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"REGULAR","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"SHORTS","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"SKINNY","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"SLASHED BACK","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"STRAIGHT SHOULDER","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"TRAPEZE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"TURN UP CIGARETTE","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Sizing/Fitting":"TWO PLEATS","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Skull":null},{"Skull":"NO","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null},{"Skull":"YES","Color Family":null,"Dark/Light Main Color":null,"Drop":null,"Embroidery Family":null,"Fabric Family":null,"Fabric weight":null,"Line":null,"Logo":null,"Print/Jacquard Family":null,"Sizing/Fitting":null}]
```

I am trying to display this data in an excel sheet, but there the excel sheet comes like this. [image]

The problem with this array is that the properties that have non null values do not occur with same frequency. For example I have `Color Family` property appearing 11 times and then let's say `Drop` appearing 2 times. I've tried to get a solution for this which was to find the key that appears the most with non null value and then concatenate other properties from other objects to it, but no success.

My desired output

```json
[
    {
        "ColorFamily": "BEIGE",
        "Dark/Light Main Color": "Dark",
        "Drop": "DEL1",
        "Embroidery Family": "SATIN STITCH",
        "FabricFamily": "COTTON"
    },
    {
        "ColorFamily": "BLACK",
        "Dark/Light Main Color": "LIGHT",
        "Drop": "DEL2",
        "Embroidery Family": "null",
        "FabricFamily": "COTTON SILK"
    },
    ...
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the array in text not as an image

Comment: can you please create a small example of input and output.?

Comment: what you mean? The desired output is the one above

Comment: how exactly are you getting the input? where are you writing the script to create the desired output? 
So you have written "I've got an array like the one underneath", can you share this array?

Comment: The array is above and desired output is written

Comment: so if BEIGE occurs once in array it can be displayed 10 times in new array?

Comment: No,basically all the objects need to have unique key,value pairs, otherwise it will be shown in the excel

Comment: @pleka7 checkout my answer and please let me know if that solves your problem or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `basic_format` and `input_data`, and you will get the desired output using the below-given code.

**Note:** this is just a code I ran for small reproducible input and output. You can change the data and play around to get the desired final output

```js
function fixMapping(basic_format = {}, input_data = []) {
    // in here we are just creating a map of all the value we have and we will be using index to match the value for different keys
    data_key_mapping = {}
    input_data.map(d => {
        Object.entries(d).map(([key, value]) => {
            if (!data_key_mapping[key]) data_key_mapping[key] = []
            if (value) data_key_mapping[key].push(value)
        })
    })
    
    // using the above mapping to finally outputting the desired output while using index to match the value in different keys and keeping other keys as null
    final_data = []
    Object.entries(data_key_mapping).map(([key, values]) => {
        values.map((value, index) => {
            if (!final_data[index]) final_data[index] = Object.assign({}, basic_format)
            final_data[index][key] = value || null
        })
    })

    return final_data;
}


basic_format = { "Color Family": null, "Drop": null }
input_data = [ { "Color Family": "BEIGE", "Drop": null }, { "Color Family": "BLACK", "Drop": null }, { "Drop": "DEL 1", "Color Family": null } ]

console.log(fixMapping(basic_format, input_data));
```

The above code will output

```json
[
  {
    "Color Family": "BEIGE",
    "Drop": "DEL 1"
  },
  {
    "Color Family": "BLACK",
    "Drop": null
  }
]
```

#### Update 1: (the need for `basic_format` variable)

We don't have the same frequency for all the keys, which will lead to inconsistent count of keys in the final object, so we will initiate every object with all the keys we want and `null` data will be overwritten by the actual value if exist.

So basically, this variable is used to give consistent structure to our final object.

If we didn't use the `basic_format`, something like this

```js
    if (!final_data[index]) final_data[index] = {}
    final_data[index][key] = value || null
```

it would yield the output as (notice the missing key `Drop` in second object)

```json
[ { "Color Family": "BEIGE", "Drop": "DEL 1" }, { "Color Family": "BLACK" } ]
```

Comment: @pleka7 good to hear that. I would really suggest playing around with the above code to understand it's exact working. I tried to add the comments for a better understanding. Still, if you feel confused with any part, just let me know.

Comment: what is interesting is that if (!final_data[index]) final_data[index] = Object.assign({}, basic_format)
            final_data[index][key] = value || null 
the object can be empty. I don't need to specify a basic format with key,value pairs, it can just be empty!

Comment: I have tried to add an explanation for your query in the above answer. Please check it out.